# Why the application looking for wrong repository in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfvc

In Visual studio online I have created project and assigned the version control TFVC. But vs code logging file shows it is looking for "Getting repository information for a Git repository at" Git repository instead of TFVC. I have created the TFVC repository using Visual Studio IDE. Why the application looking for Git repository?

Comment: When I provide the access tokens ("provide an access token manually(current experienced)") in the Team icon in the bottom shows the wrong URL (GIT repository URL instead of VSTS URL)

Comment: Are you using the TFVC plugin for VS Code? VS Code does not natively support TFVC.

Comment: Yes, i have installed version 1 1 6

Comment: Can you share your steps?

Comment: @Kumar19 did you configure `tfvc.location` in VS code? More details, you can refer https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#configure-tfvc-support.

Comment: Here is the steps... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/321052/pat-invalid-url.html